# Creating a new data frame that aggregates users into larger groups of users in R

Tags: r, data-science

The goal: Create a new data frame that takes individual user data from various locations and aggregate that into location based time series data frame.

The new table would include one row for each Locationid, with each column a part of a monthly time series (except for the first column, which would be the location ids). Data in each part of the data frame would be the percentage of action items/ total visits. A 1 in the "Action Item" column represents an action item vs a 0, which means no action is taken.

Data Currently is:

```
Userid Locationid VisitDate ActionItem
1      Loc 1      6-13      1
2      Loc 1      7-13      0
3      Loc 2      7-13      1
```

With the goal to have a data frame that looks like:

```
Locid 6-13 7-13 8-13 9-13 ...
1     1    0    0    0
2     0    1    0    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one :

```
library(reshape2)
df1=acast(df, Locationid~VisitDate, value.var="ActionItem")

df1[is.na(df1)]=0


> df1
  6-13 7-13
1    1    0
2    0    1
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked and was easy to follow. Will read up on spread as well.

Comment: glad it is help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `spread` function from `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  select(-Userid) %>%
  spread(key = VisitDate, value = ActionItem)

# Locationid 6-13 7-13
#      Loc 1    1    0
#      Loc 2   NA    1
```